# Infinite Calendar Pageload Bug - Only in Month View

Tags: calendar, nextcloud

I am running NC 24.0.2 on Ubuntu 20.04 server LAMP (php7.4-fpm), Overview has `All Checks Passed`. I have Calendar calendar: 3.4.0

All apps are functioning correctly except for (my Calendar app).

My custom log  -- only contains "app" deprecation errors
My NC loggin  -- only contains "app" deprecation errors
My Apache error log  -- has no errors besides bots trying to bad things
(i.e. NC records no errors related to this problem in its logs)

If I use browser developer tools, I can clear identify the problematic .js files:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://example.com/dist/core-common.js.map?v=3333017b50345c6c75e8: Load canceled due to load timeout
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://example.com/apps/calendar/js/calendar-main.js.map?v=8fdb5af1433fe3937dbf: Load canceled due to load timeout
```

**The specific problem is:**

The Calendar page loads infinitely and causes any browser tab to crash (tested in FF and Chromimu on Ubuntu Desktop 20.04)

The bug renders the Calendar Page completely unusable for users.

I have read multiple threads regarding this bug as it appears to be ~2 years old and has persisted across multiple releases of the Calendar App.
https://github.com/nextcloud/server/issues/30142
https://github.com/nextcloud/calendar/issues/2529
https://github.com/nextcloud/calendar/issues/3858
https://github.com/nextcloud/calendar/issues/3551
https://github.com/nextcloud/deck/issues/2428

However, none of the suggested solutions work and/or are applicable to me.

**Things that I have tried:**

1. I disabled Deck and reloaded the Calendar page in browser problem persists
2. I disabled Circles and reloaded the Calendar page in browser problem persists
3. I disabled Deck & Circles and reload Calendar page in browser problem persists
4. I also inspected the oc_properties table via phpmyadmin and did not find applicable entries (errors) that should be delete as to repair this problem according to the above threads.

My oc_properties table contains:
[image]

This suggested solution is just not applicable:
`select * from oc_properties where propertyname = '{DAV:}resourcetype';`

As Calendar is a core app, central to  the actual use of Nextcloud as a product, might someone be able to suggest a viable workaround / solution to help me get it running again?

thanks

**Update**

I updated the title of the post because this problem only seems to happen when NC Calendar page is loading in Month View in the browser tab regardless of browser

If I switch to List, Week, or Day views, the problem doesn’t exist. If I return to Month view after changing to the different views the problem does not exist.

I normally leave my NC on Calendar view in a chromium tab for easy planning

The specific way to re-create the problem that I have described, is to load the Month View in a new browser tab in any browser.

All other Calendar views opened in new browsers do not cause the infinite pageload bug.

Answer (score 1):

I had the above problem on an account that uses many different calendars (including many shared).  I can also confirm that the problem only occurs in the month view.
However, I found out that the problem disappears when I disable "limit visible events per view" in the calendar settings.